# Compatibility problem between customtkinter and tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter, customtkinter

**Compatibility problem between customtkinter tkinter?**
I use an animated background behind widget objects in my Python application. I had it working with tkinter but the project now requires using the new 'customtkinter' framework.
The code displays a flash page with the 1st image from the folder 'images' along with a 'Loading...' message. This is to disguize the loading process prior to the background automation starting. Multiple threads are used in a effort to achieve the fastest startup possible.

The problem I am having may be a compatibility issue concerning the background animation.
When the page displays, only an extremely small message 'CTkLabel' is displayed over a tiny icon sized image.
These images are what I expected and what I got.

[What I expected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2YYwR.png)  
[What I Got](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CgGNI.png)

```
import customtkinter as ctk  # Using customtkinter instead of tkinter
from PIL import Image
import os
import threading
import sys


def animate_frames(frame_list, frame_number, label, loading_text):
    frame_index = frame_number % len(frame_list)  # Get the index of the current frame
    frame = frame_list[frame_index]  # Get the frame image

    label.configure(image=frame)  # Update the label image
    frame_number += 1  # Increment frame number

    if frame_number == 1:
        loading_text.destroy()  # Remove the "Loading..." text when the animation starts

    label.after(
        60, animate_frames, frame_list, frame_number, label, loading_text
    )  # Schedule the next frame update


def run_animation(label, loading_text):
    frame_list = []  # List to hold the frames

    # Get the base directory of the script
    base_directory = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(sys.argv[0]))

    # Load the frames from the "images" directory in the base directory
    directory = os.path.join(base_directory, "images")
    for filename in sorted(os.listdir(directory)):
        if filename.endswith(".png"):
            frame_path = os.path.join(directory, filename)
            frame_image = Image.open(frame_path)
            frame_list.append(
                ctk.CTkImage(frame_image)
            )  # Use CTkImage instead of ImageTk.PhotoImage

    frame_number = 0  # Frame number for animation

    animate_frames(frame_list, frame_number, label, loading_text)  # Start animation


def main():
    root = ctk.CTk()  # Using customtkinter's CTk widget instead of Tk

    label = ctk.CTkLabel(root)  # Using customtkinter's CTkLabel widget instead of Label
    label.pack()

    # Get the base directory of the script
    base_directory = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(sys.argv[0]))

    # Load the first frame image from the "images" directory in the base directory
    first_frame_path = os.path.join(
        base_directory,
        "images",
        sorted(os.listdir(os.path.join(base_directory, "images")))[0],
    )
    first_frame_image = Image.open(first_frame_path)
    first_frame = ctk.CTkImage(
        first_frame_image
    )  # Use CTkImage instead of ImageTk.PhotoImage

    # Set the initial size of the root window based on the first frame image
    root.geometry(
        f"{first_frame_image.size[0]}x{first_frame_image.size[1]}"
    )  # Use width and height of PIL Image

    label.configure(image=first_frame)  # Set the first frame image in the label

    # Add "Loading..." text in the center of the label
    loading_text = ctk.CTkLabel(
        label, text="Loading...", font=("Arial", 16)
    )  # Using customtkinter's CTkLabel widget instead of Label
    loading_text.place(
        relx=0.5, rely=0.5, anchor=ctk.CENTER
    )  # Using customtkinter's CENTER instead of tk.CENTER

    # Create a separate thread for the animation routine
    animation_thread = threading.Thread(
        target=run_animation, args=(label, loading_text)
    )
    animation_thread.start()

    root.mainloop()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

I have tried everything suggested in the limited documentation I could find. I have never used customtkinter before and have spent hours trying logical tweeks. What I have seen so far with customtkinter is really great, but this problem baffels me. Any help will be most appreciated.

Comment: It is better to use the GitHub issues related to the repo itself.

Comment: You need to specify the size of the image in `CTkImage(...)`, otherwise it is resized to 20x20 by default.

Answer (score 0):

The default size of a CTkImage is (20x20). So every image you pass it resizes it to 20*20. If you want to display the image in its original size you need to use the `size` parameter.

For example

> frame_list.append( 
> ctk.CTkImage(frame_image))

needs to be:

```py
            frame_list.append(
                ctk.CTkImage(frame_image, size=frame_image.size)
            )
```

So this should work:

```
import customtkinter as ctk  # Using customtkinter instead of tkinter
from PIL import Image
import os
import threading
import sys


def animate_frames(frame_list, frame_number, label, loading_text):
    frame_index = frame_number % len(frame_list)  # Get the index of the current frame
    frame = frame_list[frame_index]  # Get the frame image

    label.configure(image=frame)  # Update the label image
    frame_number += 1  # Increment frame number

    if frame_number == 1:
        loading_text.destroy()  # Remove the "Loading..." text when the animation starts

    label.after(
        60, animate_frames, frame_list, frame_number, label, loading_text
    )  # Schedule the next frame update


def run_animation(label, loading_text):
    frame_list = []  # List to hold the frames

    # Get the base directory of the script
    base_directory = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(sys.argv[0]))

    # Load the frames from the "images" directory in the base directory
    directory = os.path.join(base_directory, "images")
    for filename in sorted(os.listdir(directory)):
        if filename.endswith(".jpg"):
            frame_path = os.path.join(directory, filename)
            frame_image = Image.open(frame_path)
            frame_list.append(
                ctk.CTkImage(frame_image, size=frame_image.size)
            )  # Use CTkImage instead of ImageTk.PhotoImage

    frame_number = 0  # Frame number for animation

    animate_frames(frame_list, frame_number, label, loading_text)  # Start animation


def main():
    root = ctk.CTk()  # Using customtkinter's CTk widget instead of Tk

    label = ctk.CTkLabel(root)  # Using customtkinter's CTkLabel widget instead of Label
    label.pack()

    # Get the base directory of the script
    base_directory = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(sys.argv[0]))

    # Load the first frame image from the "images" directory in the base directory
    first_frame_path = os.path.join(
        base_directory,
        "images",
        sorted(os.listdir(os.path.join(base_directory, "images")))[0],
    )
    first_frame_image = Image.open(first_frame_path)
    first_frame = ctk.CTkImage(
        first_frame_image, size=first_frame_image.size
    )  # Use CTkImage instead of ImageTk.PhotoImage

    # Set the initial size of the root window based on the first frame image
    root.geometry(
        f"{first_frame_image.size[0]}x{first_frame_image.size[1]}"
    )  # Use width and height of PIL Image

    label.configure(image=first_frame, width=first_frame_image.size[0],
                    height=first_frame_image.size[1])  # Set the first frame image in the label

    # Add "Loading..." text in the center of the label
    loading_text = ctk.CTkLabel(
        label, text="Loading...", font=("Arial", 16)
    )  # Using customtkinter's CTkLabel widget instead of Label
    loading_text.place(
        relx=0.5, rely=0.5, anchor=ctk.CENTER
    )  # Using customtkinter's CENTER instead of tk.CENTER

    # Create a separate thread for the animation routine
    animation_thread = threading.Thread(
        target=run_animation, args=(label, loading_text)
    )
    animation_thread.start()

    root.mainloop()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

[Documentation of CTkImage](https://customtkinter.tomschimansky.com/documentation/utility-classes/image)